# I need to highlight the button with a tick in flutter and fade out other two buttons in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

What I have done so far: I have three buttons in a row that have a picture and text on them(depicts reaction).

GOAL:
1)I need to highlight the button selected by the user and fade out the other two. (I am new to animation I don't know how to proceed further).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing animation like you want, I will give you the most simple and not most elegant solution without Matrix4 transformations and AnimatedBuilders, so that it will be clear what is going on.
Here is what animation do:

[image]

and here is code to reproduce:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool firstIsSelected = false;
  bool secondIsSelected = false;
  bool thirdIsSelected = false;
  bool isSubmitted = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  secondIsSelected = false;
                  thirdIsSelected = false;
                  firstIsSelected = !firstIsSelected;
                });
              },
              child: Item(
                selector: firstIsSelected,
                color: Colors.red,
                submitted: isSubmitted,

              ),
            ),
                      GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  firstIsSelected = false;
                  thirdIsSelected = false;
                  secondIsSelected = !secondIsSelected;
                  
                });
              },
              child: Item(
                selector: secondIsSelected,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                submitted: isSubmitted,

              ),
            ),
                      GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  firstIsSelected = false;
                  secondIsSelected = false;
                  thirdIsSelected = !thirdIsSelected;
                });
              },
              child: Item(
                selector: thirdIsSelected,
                color: Colors.green,
                submitted: isSubmitted,
              ),
            ),
          ],
          ),
          MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (firstIsSelected||secondIsSelected||thirdIsSelected) {
          setState(() {
            isSubmitted = !isSubmitted;
          });
        }
      },
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text('SUBMIT'),
      
    ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final bool selector;
  final bool submitted;
  const Item({
    Key key,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    this.selector = false, 
    this.submitted = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      opacity: submitted? selector ? 1 :0 : 1,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        color: color,
        width: selector?120: 80,
        height: selector?120: 80,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon I have added an image of what I want can you help me with the code for it? I searched a lot for tutorials but couldn't get through this.